# Terminology: queue versus fifo

Tags: terminology, queue

When referring to or documenting a typical lock-free circular data structure (or class or object) used to communicate between arbitrarily long asynchronous threads or processors: "queue", "fifo" or "FIFO" are commonly used. Is there a technical reason why one term might be the more accurate or better communicative usage in some situation over the other term.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6586/31260

Comment: If it's in software, then it's usually referred to as "queue".  If it's in hardware, then it's usually referred to as "FIFO".  This is based just on my own experience.

Comment: If the buffer is a circular buffer and bounded (meaning there is a maximum capacity which cannot be grown and beyond which operations will be denied) Circular buffer is fine. If it is a concurrent linked queue, the name should say so. There are other aspects besides the input-output characteristics (in particular size limitations, thread-safety, and time complexity per operation) that needs to be conveyed.

Comment: There is also a debate between whether a name should be "abstract / high-level" vs. "descriptive / detailed". However, such a debate may be opinion-based, and therefore are not suitable for the StackExchange network. See: "good subjective vs. bad subjective".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terms FIFO and queue are interchangeable.

In most programming languages, *queue* and *stack* terms are preferred to *FIFO* and *LIFO*, and to many programmers, they will feel more descriptive. [As Nick Alexeev noted](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/246929/terminology-queue-versus-fifo#comment495975_246929), *FIFO* is more common in hardware.

Finally, don't use lowercase *fifo*: *FIFO* is an acronym, which means that it should be written in capitals.

Comment: As pointed out in the other answer, the terms are _not_ interchangeable in all cases.  All FIFOs are queues, but not all queues are FIFOs.

Answer (score 3):

Queue can also mean a priority queue or a timing queue where elements are pulled out based on how soon or in which order they should be handled they should be handled. This is common in event based architectures to handle timeouts. It may or may not be an actual data structure or just a virtual one that you pop an event off from.

However in the context of data structures queue and FIFO are interchangeable.